# Error when I run re-indexing data after model changed

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have User model and specified index for only `username` field => It worked:

```
class User {

   @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.analyzed)
   private String username;

   @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.no)
   private String email;
}
```

After that, I added index for `email` field and & want to *re-index* data:
    class User {

```
   @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.analyzed)
   private String username;

   @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.analyzed)
   private String email;
}
```

I got error from Java side:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapper for [email] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:
>   [mapper [email] has different [index] values]

Comment: You cannot change the mapping once created. You need to delete your index and recreate it.

Comment: I did that, and it worked. But my data is large (n GB), so I don't want to delete index and recreate it. Please help me if you have any other ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you really need to think about your mapping **before** pouring GB of data into your index since that takes quite some time to build. You can still adopt the [zero downtime](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime) strategy if you want.

Comment: @Val as val mentioned you, Yes you should be carefull about your mappings as tweaking them again will have to reindex the data. you can use aliases for zero downtime

Comment: Is there any Java sample code/tool/library to resolve this issue? I saw haystack for Python language. I'm looking for a same one for java